# chrome vs firefox - id name changes width of table. no CSS involved. Possible AdBlock Issue

Tags: html, google-chrome

I've got a table that's behaving oddly in Chrome. If I change the name of the ID it changes the width to 0 or not. With the zero width it doesn't display.

here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kdubs/W6GTE/

the line in question is this :

```
 <table id="ad_table">
```

If I change ad_table to anything else it works in Chrome. It works in Firefox all the time. Any thoughts ?

Comment: do you have AdBlock extention in chrome?

Comment: chrome sucks dude, I have many issues and differences on chrome. The last one is with @fontface on all other browsers works fine but on chrome wont work :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kokers was right. the AdBlock extension saw the "ad_table" and blocked it. turn off AdBlock and all is fine. now do I tell the AdBlock folks...